# What does COLLATE pg_catalog."default" do on text attribute in postgres database table?

Tags: postgresql

One of the fields while creating the table is described as below

```
id text COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
```

Comment: `COLLATE pg_catalog."default"` is a noise, you can safely remove it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's just telling that you're using default `lc_collate` for this column.

But what's the default collate? Use `SHOW` to discover that.

```
SHOW lc_collate;
```

PostgreSQL allows to create columns with different types of collation:

```
CREATE TABLE collate_test
(
  default_collate text, --Default collation
  custom_collate text COLLATE pg_catalog."C" --Custom collation
);
```

Did you see the difference?

More info about collation is on [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/collation.html):

> The collation feature allows specifying the sort order and character
>   classification (...)

Comment: so is it useful to add or nit ?

Comment: What does this city text OPTIONS (column_name 'city') NULL COLLATE pg_catalog."default" mean, then?

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL, the `COLLATE` keyword is used to specify the collation for a character data type column i.e. how the data in a column is sorted and compared.

In the given SQL code snippet, `COLLATE pg_catalog."default"` is used to specify the default collation for the character varying columns. In other words, this line of code is explicitly stating that the `id` column should use the default collation provided by PostgreSQL for sorting and comparison operations.

The default collation is determined by the database's default settings, which are usually set based on the database's locale. It defines how strings are ordered, compared, and searched in queries. If you don't explicitly specify a collation, PostgreSQL will use the default collation for character columns.